# How to drive rect transform on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a script editing the some values of RectTransform and I want write "Some values driven by Script" to RectTransform in Editor.

I'm making a script editing the some values of RectTransform.

I want to do this
[image]

I do this
[image]

How can I add "Some Values Driven By **" text?

Comment: Can you also include how did you disable the rect transform component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RectTransform`s seem to disable when you add elements to a struct called `DrivenRectTransformTracker` [defined in the `RectTransform` scripting implementation](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/e740821767d2290238ea7954457333f06e952bad/Runtime/Transform/ScriptBindings/RectTransform.bindings.cs#L47).

The case that you describe is done in the [`GridLayoutGroup` implementation](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uGUI/blob/2019.1/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Layout/GridLayoutGroup.cs#L224) which is a protected member of the class the `GridLayoutGroup` inherits from, [`LayoutGroup`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uGUI/blob/2019.1/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Layout/LayoutGroup.cs#L44).

The documentation for it can be found in the [Unity Scripting Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DrivenRectTransformTracker.html).